# Uploading files in Asp.NET Core using MongoDb

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core

I would like to upload an image using Asp.net core and MongoDb; however, I am not able to find the property `GridFS` in `MongoDatabase` class . I have checked the Google and did not have any luck.

The method in which  I need to change `GridFS` to something else:

```
private async Task StoreImage(Computer computer, IFormFile file)
        {
            var imageId = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();
            computer.ImageId = imageId.ToString();
            var filter = Builders<Computer>.Filter.Eq("_id", new ObjectId(computer.Id));
            var update = Builders<Computer>.Update.Set("ImageId", computer.ImageId);
            await db.Computers.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
            db.GridFS.Upload(file.ToBson(), file.FileName, new MongoGridFSCreateOptions
            {
                Id = imageId,
                ContentType = file.ContentType
            });
        }
```

Does anyone know the correct way to upload a file in MongoDB using ASP.net Core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class CdnDbContext
{
    public IGridFSBucket GridFsBucket { get; set; }
    public CdnDbContext()
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

        var connectionString = config.GetConnectionString("MongoCdn");
        var connection = new MongoUrl(connectionString);
        var settings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(connection);
        var client = new MongoClient(settings);
        var database = client.GetDatabase(connection.DatabaseName);
        GridFsBucket = new GridFSBucket(database);
    }
}
```